# Looking for charts library that supports linked events

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, open-source

I am looking for a Library that allows me to create Charts like the "[Annotated Time Lines](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html)" that are e.g. used on Google Finance. I can't use the Google API because it relies on Flash and my chart should not only work on all common browsers but also be usable with mobile devices like the ipad.
I don't need all of the features of Google's Solution, but displaying linked event flags in the chart is an essential requirement and the ability to arbitrarily zoom and pan the chart would also be nice, the latter feature is however not a must on mobile devices and older browsers.

A serverside solution that transparently generates plain image charts if flash (or other client features like canvas-elements) is not available on the client would also be ok, I have asp.net mvc 2 running on the serverside.

An open source solution would be great, but a commercial library or component is also an option.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about http://highcharts.com, their API is very complete

Comment: Doesn't look bad, thanks. The only thing I'm really missing in the samples is mousewheel support for zooming. Do you know if this can be added without a hassle?

Comment: I'm not sure about mousewheel support, sorry

Comment: What's an indirect developer?  `Each person who directly or indirectly creates an application or user interface containing Highcharts is considered a developer.`  If I just write SQL all day and it's used by a UI that uses Highcharts, does that make me an indirect developer?

Comment: @Greg, I assume if you are just writing the SQL someone else has asked of you, and you didn't code the UI that uses Highcharts, you don't count as a developer. I figure an indirect developer would be if I wrote .net wrappers around Highcharts, and then you used my dll to write your application.

Comment: @Prescott: I would hope it's something like that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Simon, look this for pan and zoom tool http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7922

Answer (score 2):

A popular opensource Javascript plotting library is the [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) library (JQuery plugin). More information:

- [Flot Sample with a basic annotated time line](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html)
- [Flot usage on the web (many samples)](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage)

Answer (score 1):

[www.hightcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com) is amazing

Answer (score 0):

mmm, I think you can extend the Highcharts library with no hassle, they have pretty good documentation, and also Is really easy to understand their api and code. I suggest you, first implement the linked events, and then with some free time study the code to add that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://g.raphaeljs.com/

(I've used Raphael.js extensively for http://radiancejs.com.)

You'll have to do the scrolling to zoom thing yourself, however.